# TYPO3 inline fluid condition and typoscriptObjectPath

Tags: typo3, fluid

I search for a solution for inline fluid condition and typoscriptObjectPath.

work fine:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.currentDate" />
```

work fine:

```
<f:if condition="{price.day} == {f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'lib.currentDate')}">
<f:then>work</f:then>
<f:else>dont work</f:else>
</f:if>
```

work fine:

```
{f:if(condition:'{price.day} == \'Sunday\'',then:'active',else:'test')}
```

**DONT work**

```
{f:if(condition:'{price.day} == \'{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'lib.currentDate')}\'',then:'active',else:'test')}
```

how can i use the right inline code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to resolve `lib.currentDate` cObject within your view, as you can just *copy* its output into fluid variable. It will avoid any problems with nested quotes, brackets etc. etc... Of course I assume, that's in combination with fluid template of the `PAGE`:

```
lib.currentDate = TEXT
lib.currentDate {
    data = date:U
    strftime = %A
}

page = PAGE
page {
    # ....
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        # ....
        variables {
            mainContent < styles.content.get
            currentDate < lib.currentDate
        }
    }
}
```

so you can use it in condition just like:

```
<f:if condition="{price.day} == {currentDate}">That's today!</f:if>

<!-- or... -->
{f:if(condition:'{price.day} == {currentDate}', then: 'active', else: 'not-active')}
```

Of course if you're working in the plugin's context, you can do the same with `assign` method within your action, like:

```
$this->view->assign('currentDate', strftime('%A',date('U')));
```

Note you have also other options:

1. Create custom if ViewHelper, which will be useful when `price.day` and `currentDate` are different types and requires type conversion before comparison.
2. Create `transient` field in your `price` model, which' getter compares day field with `strftime('%A',date('U'))` and return `boolean` value, so you can use it directly as:

   ```
   <f:if condition="{price.myTransientField}">Hooray!</f:if>
   ```